# scene builder won't open

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

When i right click the FXML document and click open with scene builder the scene builder opens on my taskbar but if i click it, it will not show anything can anyone please help me?

```
  package application;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
     import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.image.Image;
   import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
   import javafx.stage.Stage;

 public class Main extends Application {
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(
                "/application/MyView.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(
                getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_CASPIAN);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
   }
 }
```

This is my main class

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found out that it is a bug and you have to open Scene Builder from your desktop and:

- File>Preferences>Reset To BuiltIn Defaults
- File>Open recent>clear menu

Comment: Thanks...this fixed it for me also :)

Answer (score 0):

I installed scene builder from a different maker (gluon)

Works wonderfully.

Associate the FXML files in your SO to that they are open by this application instead of the "normal" one and you can forget about this problem.